# Copying Data from Shared memory segment causes seg fault in the client ( semaphores & shared memory)

Tags: c, synchronization, shared-memory, semaphore, memcpy

I am trying to write a simple producer and consumer program( two unrelated processes). , with shared memory & semaphores. I use the semaphores empty & full as conditional variables, and I memcpy the data into the shared memory segment from the producer. And, I try to memcpy the data into a local variable in the consumer, but thats resulting in a seg fault. It is very strange, and I couldnt figure out whats happening. Here is the code.

Common part for the Producer & consumer ( semaphore & shared memorycreation) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

struct a
{
int a;
int b;
}a_s;
void wait(int semid)
{
int err,nsops=1;
struct sembuf *sops = (struct sembuf *) malloc(sizeof(struct sembuf));
sops[0].sem_num = 0;
sops[0].sem_op = -1;
sops[0].sem_flg = 0;
err=semop(semid, sops, nsops);
if(err < 0)
    printf(" unable to do the sop \n");
}

void signal(int semid)
{
int err,nsops=1;
struct sembuf *sops = (struct sembuf *) malloc(sizeof(struct sembuf));      
sops[0].sem_num = 0;
sops[0].sem_op = 1;
sops[0].sem_flg = 0;
err=semop(semid, sops, nsops);
if(err < 0)
    printf(" unable to do the sop \n");
}


int main()
{
int i, err;
int full,empty;
key_t full_key = 1234, empty_key = 5678;
int sem_flg = IPC_CREAT | 0666;
int nsems = 1;
int nsops = 2;
    int shmid;
void *string;
void *s;
int shm_key = 9999;

struct a *a_str;
/*****************************************/

empty = semget(empty_key, nsems, sem_flg);
if(empty < 0)
    printf(" failed to initialize the semaphore \n");

semctl(empty, 0, SETVAL, 1) ;
/****************************************/
full = semget(full_key, nsems, sem_flg);
if(full < 0)
    printf(" failed to initialize the semaphore \n");

semctl(full, 0, SETVAL, 0) ;    

/*****************************************/
shmid = shmget(shm_key, 30, IPC_CREAT|0666); 
if(shmid < 0) 
    printf(" unable to create shmem \n");
else
    printf(" created shm \n");

string = shmat( shmid, NULL, 0); 
if( string == (void * ) (-1))
    printf(" unable to attach the string \n");
else
    printf(" success with shmat \n");
s = string;
/******************************************/
```

Producer : inputting the data

```
while(1)
{
    wait(empty);
    sleep(1);
    memcpy( string, (void *) a_str, sizeof(struct a));
    printf(" wrote the string \n");
    signal(full);
}
```

Consumer : copying the data, and displaying

```
while(1)
{

wait(full);
printf(" after full \n");
memcpy((void *)a_str, (void *)s, sizeof(struct a));
printf(" copied the memory from string \n");
printf(" a %d b %d \n",((struct a *)a_str)->a, ((struct a *)a_str)->b);
sleep(1);
memcpy(s, string, 7);


signal(empty);
}

return 0;
}
```

Could anybody please let me know why its seg faulting?? I am just copying from a memory segment, with the address. what could possibly go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> Could anybody please let me know why its seg faulting??

You did not initialize `a_str`, this could be fixed by

```
a_str = malloc(sizeof(*a_str));
```

The typical using-uninitialized-pointer, a.k.a. wild pointer, problem.

---

By the way, POSIX IPC API is better than System V IPC API. See

- `mq_overview (7)`      - overview of POSIX message queues
- `sem_overview (7)`     - overview of POSIX semaphores
- `shm_overview (7)`     - overview of POSIX shared memory

Comment: @saipallavi Accept or upvote is a better way to say thanks :-)